# The $.ajax() function inside a function is not invoked while the function is invoked

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a JavaScript function on a webpage I am creating. The $.ajax() function is called inside the previously mentioned function. When the so called function is invoked, every line of the function gets executed except the ajax part. Only after every possible code line of the entire file is executed, the ajax part gets executed. Could you please help me with this problem?

fyi the following is the function I am talking about;

```
function submitDetails(){

       
        var sendObject = new Object();
        sendObject.idCustomer = <?php echo $user_customer_id ?>;
        sendObject.name = customerName.value;

        var convertedObject = JSON.stringify(sendObject);
       
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: BASE_URL+"action/method1",
            data : {
                parameter : convertedObject
            },
            success : function(responseData) {
                
                var response = JSON.parse(responseData);

                if(response.status=="SUCCESS"){
                  
                    console.log(true);
                    }
                else{
                    console.log(false);
                }
            },
            error : function() {
               console.log("error");

            }
    });
       
    }
```

Comment: AJAX is **asynchronous**.

Comment: Maybe this resource can help you to learn about asynchronous code: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous